# Absolute Position PopUp Div Doesn't Show in FullCalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar, css-position

I want to display a popup when an event is clicked in FullCalendar.  Based on my CSS, the div is created and positioned properly, however, the div is not visible.  Visibility is not set to 'hidden'.  Note, when I change the position to 'fixed', it does show.  I've tried messing with the z-index to no avail.

CSS:

```
._detail {
  position:absolute;
  left:-260px;
  font-size:1em;
  padding:5px;
  height:150px;
  width:250px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid darkgrey;
}
```

Basic JS:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  // create div with class '_detail', fill it with stuff
  jsEvent.target.appendChild(_div); }
```

Comment: Need more context including HTML.

Comment: @MikeBrant Are you familiar with FullCalendar?  I'm doing a basic [eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/).  Do you need more context outside of the calendar?

Comment: Interestingly, the div will display if I call the popup with eventMouseover instead of eventClick.  But only sometimes

Comment: I am using this to show the popup z-index:7778; position:absolute; and it works for me. Try giving the exact z-index value. If your value is lower that might not work either. If it doesn't work. Try clicking the event and notice if you see any change in the scrollbar of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jsEvent.target.appendChild(_div);
```

is stupid.  It will append the div to a span.  I decided to append the popup div to the calendar container.  Work around that doesn't answer the technical question, but works for me.

Comment: Just an afterthought here - have you looked at something like qTip? You can easily attach this to the `element` parameter of the `eventRender` callback. And the qTip can be configured to be triggered on click.

Comment: thanks.  I've used jTip before.  I like it but my needs are simpler and lighter here.

Answer (score -1):

if there is a parent div for pop set position: relative to parent div which contain your popup otherwise set position relative to your main wrapper div for page

Comment: you use relative positioning for displacing something from its normal position.  Not to position something relative to an element.  Yes, I've got that.

Comment: position absolute work better with position relative property. you are using left:-260px may be just because of this your pop is displaying -260 px left from your body which is out of screen resolution.so just set position relative to your body tag or main wrapper div of your page.